# Access file robots.txt from subdomains on main domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I use codeigniter and my robots.txt file located in the root, but it can be accessed only from main domain. Search robots trying to access it from subdomains(i use it for locales):
Example:

```
my.com/robots.txt - OK
en.my.com/robots.txt - FAIL
```

How can I redirect from xx.my.com/robots.txt to my.com/robots.txt ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `RedirectMatch`

```
RedirectMatch 301 /robots.txt http://my.com/robots.txt
```